# Connecting circles with lines cover all circles using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, polygon

[image]

I'm really new to postgis.

I have trouble to find out the coding for connecting circles.
You can figure out what I'm trying to do from the image I uploaded.
I want to connect the circles which have the same numberings by outerline.

My first trial was using st_convexhull, st_concavehull but both of them does not make the covering polygons as I wanted.

like the following:

**create table public.cover_line as

SELECT ST_Boundary(ST_ConcaveHull(geom,0.99)) as convex
FROM circles;**

Is there someone can help me?

Comment: If you look at the online Help for St_ConcaveHull, you can add a Group By clause.

Comment: look at te in this scenario:https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/342723/120129...

Answer (score 1):

This task is simply solved with the help of QGIS tools, but if I understand you correctly, you would like to find its solution using PostGIS functions, as a result the solution of the problem is the following:
For initial data, see Figure 1, the names of my tables are abstract, replace them with your own
[image]
1) Due to the fact that you are working with point buffer zones, you need to first determine their central points, as an option with this query:

```
create table buff_k21p6_aeroporty_centroid as
SELECT ST_Centroid (geom)
FROM buff_k21p6_aeroporty
```

The result, see in Figure 2
[image]
2) Now create in pairs (links from two adjacent point buffer zones common zones), for example

```
create table buff_k21p6_aeroporty_buff as
SELECT ST_ConvexHull (ST_Collect (geom)) As geom
FROM buff_k21p6_aeroporty, k21p6_aeroporty
WHERE
buff_k21p6_aeroporty.gid = 4 or
buff_k21p6_aeroporty.gid = 11;
```

The result, see Figure 3
[image]
3) Combine adjacent paired zones into a common, for example

```
create table buff_k21p6_aeroporty_buff_union as
SELECT * from buff_k21p6_aeroporty_buff
UNION ALL
SELECT * from buff_k21p6_aeroporty_buff2;
```

The result, see Figure 4
[image]
4) As I understand you need the boundary of the general buffer polygon, then run the query:

```
create table buff_k21p6_aeroporty_buff_boundary as
SELECT ST_Boundary (geom)
FROM buff_k21p6_aeroporty_buff_union
```

The result, see Figure 5
[image]
I hope that I answered your question and was able to direct you to the right path, good luck.